# Force react-select to show all options using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, react-select

I'm trying to implement this with elasticsearch and it is working But how i can force this show results which can be different from the searched terms? For example i search ardino, The elasticsearch give me the word arduino but then react-select does not show that result because ardino does not contain arduino. I know the idea of this library is exactly that and it is working ok, but i have most of the things already implemented and it is only missing that part.

The handle is giving the right behavior and it is populating the options correctly.

Thank you

```
<Select
  name= {this.state.selectedOption}
  value={this.state.selectedOption}
  isSearchable={true}
  onChange = {(val) => {

    this._handleSearch(val.value)
  }}
  onInputChange = {(val) => {

    this._handleSearch(val)
  }}
  options={this.state.options}
/>
```

Comment: Some ideas. Use the Async Select component, so any time the input changes, you will get fresh results. Also, you can manually add whatever you want to the `this.state.options` array.

Comment: Thank you ! Your answer i according the answer Avremel Kaminetzky below. It helps thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Async component](https://react-select.com/async) which can simplify your code. You will not need the `onChange` handler anymore.

`isSearcheable` is [true by default](https://react-select.com/props), no need to specify.

In answer to your question: Make sure you are passing in `label` and `value` keys with each result option. If you want to customize any of the results, for example adding the search term in the results, you can manually manipulate the `options` array.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/lib/Async';

class Search extends Component {

    state = {inputValue: ""}

    onInputChange = (inputValue) => {
        this.setState({ inputValue });
    };

    getSearchResults = async (inputValue) => {
        // elastic search results
        let options = await fetch(`searchElastic/${inputValue}`);

        // input value of drop-down
        const inputValue = this.state.inputValue;

        // manually add input field as an option in drop-down
        if (inputValue.length > 0)
            options.unshift({label: inputValue, value: inputValue})

        // async handling of new props
        return options.map(opt => {
            return {label: opt.name, value: opt.value}
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <AsyncSelect
            onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
            loadOptions={this.getSearchResults}
        />
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot !!